# Git how to delete branches called -merged and --merged

Tags: git

I was trying to delete obsolete branches.  I typed in `git branch -merged master` and it created a branch called -merged.  Then I typed `git branch --merged master` and it created a branch called --merged.

I try to delete these branches with `git branch -d -merged` and I get "did you mean --merged".  I type `git branch -d --merged` and it gives me a usage printout.

How can I delete these?

`git branch` output:

```
 $ git branch
  suggestions
  delete-form
* master
  –-merged
  –merged
```

Comment: I don't think git will let you create branches named `--merged` like that.
Can you show us the output of `git branch`?

Comment: @PhilTaprogge please see edit

Comment: Huh... doesn't work for me, in any case. Have you tried quoting the branch name after adding `--` e.g. `git branch -D -- "--merged"`?

Comment: @PhilTaprogge that doesn't work either.  Do you think there's any problem with deleting the files named `-merged` and `--merged` in `.git/refs/heads`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to .git/refs/heads and delete the branches there.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git branch -D -- --merged
git branch -D -- -merged
```

The `--` tells Git to stop looking for flags/options.

Comment: I am getting `error: branch '-merged' not found.` when I try that

Comment: is it safe to delete the file I found here `.git/refs/heads` with the name `-merged`